# Uploading blob file to parse it and insert rows in sql azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

For one subject in college I need to use `Windows Azure`. Notice that I am Java dev and a total newbie to Windows itself and cs.

My project is quite simple. I am going to do a [Layar](http://layar.com) server.

I already have a `Service` which returs a mocked point of interest in json format. Now I would like to do my massive insert in the sql azure db to do spatial searches afterwards.

I was thinking of:

- Creating a cvs file with all rows.
- Upload it as blob.
- Parse it with a  `Worker role` and insert it in the sql azure db.

Questions:

- Do you think this is the correct approach?
- Is cvs fine?
- What do you use for a massive insertion to sql azure?
- Is there a way to "Annotate" my model class to create an entity in my db? Should I do the mapping by hand?

Comment: Why not to import the CSV file directly to the database using bcp.exe or do you necessarily want to leverage the worker role?

Comment: This utility allows you to bulk copy data between MSSQL and data files http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(SQL.105).aspx   and it's included in any MSSQL installation but I think you already googled that.  But if you decide to go the "worker role way", make sure you leverage the Bulk Copy API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx  Otherwise your insertion operations will be painfully slow and in addition you will end up with a huge transaction log (hence this leads to a bigger database size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to import data into sql azure, here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way.aspx

You have basically the following options:

- SQL Server BCP Utility,
- SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)
- Import and Export Data and SQL Server Studio (SSMS).
- Bulk Copy API